# fileclose in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, file

i'm using fileopen() function to open the file, after doing all the works i'm using fileclose() to close the file. but when i access the file again it returns already the file is opened by another process.

sample:

```
Dim intFile As Integer = FreeFile()
FileOpen(intFile, mstrFilename, OpenMode.Binary, OpenAccess.Read, OpenShare.LockWrite)
FileClose(intFile)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you could use the [`System.IO.File`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx) class for all file operations.

Sample:

```
var fs = File.OpenWrite();
var info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("Test of the OpenWrite method.");
fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
fs.Close();
```